# New Leaf Town Trading

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So if I have two accounts in my town, one the mayor and one not, can I give my non-mayor account items? Or are they kept separate completely? I want to give him my balloon set since I'm not using it in my main house at all and his is barren since I haven't used him much.

Comment: You *should* be able to mail it to them. I don't know for certain, as I've only played with a single character.

Answer (score 3):

You can drop items on the ground in Animal Crossing New Leaf and another character can just come along and pick them up. They will pretty much stay there unless something/someone decides to build in that location (I juggle all four characters for what sounds like the same reason as you are, they display sets and collections :))

You can mail the items if you want but it adds in a delay.

Just of note: I have swapped characters pretty fast and it has made my characters trip from time to time... Only just the one time for each character so its not too horribly bad, but apparently they do not like you to swap characters so fast. Its not been a deal breaker for me, but just in case this bugs you.

Comment: Did you change the game clock before the switch at all? That for sure makes you trip

Comment: @BenBrocka Nope. I just did very quick hops to pay off all four initial houses at once and every time I logged in a new character it would trip once.